# how can i map <Alt> itself on vim/nvim to <Esc>

Tags: vim, neovim, alt-attribute

I want to map (from the `init.vim` file) the  key to the  key ON VIM/NVIM because its closer to my thumb.
The only thing I found online was binding <Alt + key>, not  itself.
Is this even possible?

I've tried to do `:imap <Alt> <Esc>` or `:imap <A-> <Esc>` and nothing works.
Any help would be great!

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible in Vim itself. You would have to remap your keys using some OS-specific hacks. There should be plenty of instructions on how to map Caps Lock to Esc.